# 2sxc 11 Font icon picker Material Icons

Tags: 2sxc, google-material-icons

I use 2sxc 11 and want to use the Material Icons.
I have the Woff, Woff2 and TTF files but I dont get the icons to pick.

My thought is that it doesn't work because Material does not work with unique classes but a string in the  tag.
Is there a way to configure this so I can use the Font Icon Picker?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues - this should work IMHO.

An important detail to note: the icon-picker scans the CSS file for the classes it should provide/show, and this only works if the CSS file is loaded from the same domain. So the WOFF can be loaded externally, and the css for the page itself can also come from google etc. but for the icon picker to work, you need a css file on the same domain (usually in the same app).

That's a security limitation in js/css.

Comment: Can the problem be that Material Icons don't use unique classes?
Fontawesome uses stuff like: <i class="fa fa-arrow"></i>
But material icons are defined like: <i class="material-icons">arrow</i>
Is the Picker not made to work with that?

Comment: I don't see a problem but I'm not sure. Best try to configure it, then use F12 to see what's being generated in the dropdown. If it's clearly not working, post an issue - ideally with a configured app for reproduction.

Comment: I have tried the configuration. But I don't seem to get it to work. I have added an issue on Github: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2105 please let me know if it is anything that I did wrong, or if I need to add more information.